# How to use etcdctl without supplying certificates

Tags: ssl, certificate, coreos, etcd

Heey All,

Maybe a very stupid question but I've got a CoreOS cluster with SSL between the cluster nodes. I've set up fleet and etcd within my cloud config.

fleetctl works quite nice. I don't have to supply any certificates but when I use etcdctl I'm forced supply certificate paths like this:

```
etcdctl --ca-file /home/core/etcd/certificates/ca.pem --cert-file /home/core/etcd/certificates/coreos.pem --key-file /home/core/etcd/certificates/coreos-key.pem --endpoint "https://10.129.1.226:2379" get /test/key
```

Is there a way that etcd2 can be configured in such a way that etcdctl doesn't need the certificate paths every time like:

```
etcdctl get /test/key
```

Part of my Cloud config:

```
write_files:
  # tell etcd2 and fleet where our certificates are going to live:
  - path: /run/systemd/system/etcd2.service.d/30-certificates.conf
    permissions: 0644
    content: |
      [Service]
      # client environment variables
      Environment=ETCD_CA_FILE=/home/core/etcd/certificates/ca.pem
      Environment=ETCD_CERT_FILE=/home/core/etcd/certificates/coreos.pem
      Environment=ETCD_KEY_FILE=/home/core/etcd/certificates/coreos-key.pem
      # peer environment variables
      Environment=ETCD_PEER_CA_FILE=/home/core/etcd/certificates/ca.pem
      Environment=ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/home/core/etcd/certificates/coreos.pem
      Environment=ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/home/core/etcd/certificates/coreos-key.pem
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the README.md of the [etcdctl](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/tree/master/etcdctl) tool you can set environment vars for the client.

You can test it:

1: verify it's not working

```
core@sylvana-coreos ~/docker $ etcdctl --endpoint "https://10.129.1.226:2379" ls /test
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
error #0: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

2: export correct env vars

```
export ETCDCTL_CA_FILE=/your/path/to/ca.pem
export ETCDCTL_CERT_FILE=/your/path/to/cert.pem
export ETCDCTL_KEY_FILE=/your/path/to/key.pem
```

3: verify it's working

```
core@sylvana-coreos ~/docker $ etcdctl --endpoint "https://10.129.1.226:2379" ls /test
/test/key
```